# Ruby partially retrieve large amount of records and iterate over them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, collections, iterator, persistent-storage

I'm newbie in Ruby but I have a lot of experience in other programming languages. I need to iterate over large amount of records (from db or any persistent storage). Storage engine allows me to retrieve records partially by ranges. In PHP I usually write custom iterator that loads range of records iterate over them and when need loads next part of records and forget about previous part. Some trade-off between script memory usage and count of request to storage. Something like this (copied from comments [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php)):

```
class Database_Result_Iterator {
...
private $_db_resource = null;
private $_loaded = false;
private $_valid = false;

function rewind() {
    if ($this->_db_resource) {
        mysql_free($this->_db_resource);
        $this->_db_resource = null;
    }
    $this->_loaded = false;
    $this->_valid = false;
}

function valid() {
    if ($this->_loaded) {
        $this->load();
    }
    return $this->_valid;
}

private function load() {
    $this->_db_resource = mysql_query(...);
    $this->_loaded = true;
    $this->next(); // Sets _valid
}
```

}

How such approach is transformed in Ruby? I.e. I have some class *Voter* and method **get_votes** that returns all *votes* belong to current voter object. It is possible to retrieve not an array with all votes but collection of votes with possibility to iterate over it. How should I implement it?

**UPDATE**

Please not consider ActiveRecord and RDBMS as only one possible storage. And what about Redis as storage and commands like LRANGE? I'm interested in common code pattern for solution such kind of problem in Ruby.

Comment: you can check out the documentation about active record here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html .. keyword: limit and offset for example..

Comment: And what about Redis as storage? I'm interested in common code pattern for solution such kind of problem in Ruby.

Comment: if you are using redis, I would recommend using the redis gem..https://github.com/redis/redis-rb

Comment: As far as I know that gem implements only standard Redis protocol. But I'm looking for collection implementation that incapsulates iteration logic. Basically, it is no matter what kind of storage engine will be behind such collection.

Comment: How do you partially retrieve a record? They are retrieved entirely or not at all. Perhaps you meant you want to "retrieve a partial record"?

Comment: No, I each record entirely filled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't see the point of this question.
AR is an API for querying RDBMS and that's how you do it in AR.

If you want to do redis you'll have to either write it yourself at the driver level or find a similar abstraction to AR for Redis... I think DataMapper had a redis adapter.
If there is a universal way to do this for any data store it is likely in DataMapper, but the basic pattern to follow when creating your own would be to look at how AR implements find_each/find_in_batches and do it for your store of choice.

Comment: Excellent! I already look at find_each implementation. Thank you for mention about DataMapper.

Answer (score 5):

From the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches) on Ruby on Rails:

```
User.all.each do |user|
  NewsLetter.weekly_deliver(user)
end
```

Is very innefficient. You probably want to do most of the filtering in the database, to start with. ActiveRecord offers a method called `find_each` for this:

```
User.find_each(:batch_size => 5000) do |user|
  NewsLetter.weekly_deliver(user)
end
```

The `:batch_size` parameter allows to fetch slices of data instead of getting the entire resultset. Extremely helpfull in most cases.

But, you probably don't want to operate on all records in the first place:

```
User.with_newsletter.each do |user| 
   NewsLetter.weekly_deliver(user)
end
```

Where `with_newsletter` is a so called [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes).

Comment: Thank you, I see guides and this example. But I looking for common code pattern for manual implementation. Or decision not do it =)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use `find_each` (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_each). This lets you iterate through a large dataset by loading in a small number, iterating over them, then loading in another batch and so on.

```
User.find_each do |user|
  user.do_some_stuff
end
```

will iterate through all users without loading a bajillion of them into memory at once.

Comment: Good enought for database but is not common solution not it?